# How to init CORBA in Quarkus Java 17 application?

Tags: java, quarkus, corba

In `pom.xml` there is dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.openjdk-orb</groupId>
  <artifactId>openjdk-orb-jakarta</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I try to init CORBA ORB:

```java
var properties = new Properties();
var args = new String[]{"-ORBInitRef", nameServiceReference);
var orb = ORB.init(args, properties);  // this fails
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/NamedValue
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.NamedValue
```

What I tried is to use different CORBA implementations including Glassfish and Jacorb:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jacorb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacorb-omgapi</artifactId>
  <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But the problem still exists.

In stubs generated by IDL compiler there is `NamedValue` interface and `_NamedValueStub` class:

```java
public interface NamedValue extends NamedValueOperations, org.omg.CORBA.Object, org.omg.CORBA.portable.IDLEntity 
{
} // interface NamedValue

public class _NamedValueStub extends org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl implements org.omg.CORBA.NamedValue
{

  // Type-specific CORBA::Object operations
  private static String[] __ids = {"IDL:CORBA/NamedValue:1.0"};

  // ............
}
```

The IDL defining it contains:

```
module CORBA
{
    interface NamedValue { };
};
```

Any workaround for this? How to init ORB properly?

Comment: It looks that Quarkus class loader can't find the class.

Comment: For some reason when you run `quarkus dev` then classes are NOT visible but when you build uber-jar, then classes are packed in .jar and loaded successfully.